# Find the row contain two column values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have csv below

```
ID,Name1,Name2
1,A,A
2,B,B
3,C,D
4,0,Z
5,0,Z
```

Find all row which is having `Name1 ==0 and Name2==Z`

Expected out is

```
4,0,Z
5,0,Z
```

My Code

```
df[df['Name1'].str.contains("0") & df['Name2'].str.contains('Z')]
```

any alternate way?

Comment: `contains` is probably going to be slower than `==`, if you don't want substring matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized operations provide the fastest run:

```
df[(df.Name1 == "0") & (df.Name2 == "Z")]
```

> ```
>    ID  Name1  Name2
> 3   4      0      Z
> 4   5      0      Z
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another take, using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
df.query('Name1.str.contains("0") and Name2.str.contains("Z")')

# or

df.query('Name1 == "0" and Name2 == "Z"')

#   ID   Name1  Name2
# 3 4    0      Z
# 4 5    0      Z
```

As in the comments suggestion `contains` is a bit slower than using `==` as the first will try to match substrings.